# JQuery resizeable and dragable divs positioning problems

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, html, draggable, resizable

I'm having trouble properly positioning some divs within a larger div and having them behave as I want.

The source and a preview is here: http://jsbin.com/usuniw/6/edit

**Problem 1**

When the hidden div is unhidden it appears under the div I want it to appear inside. Once the dive inside is resized (using a handle on the left hand side) it pops into place

**Problem 2**

When resizing the originally hidden div it moves outside the boundry of it's parent rather than aligning itself to the right-hand side of it.

Thanks for any help you can give.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, you have the `#selectedResult` element set as float right which is causing it to appear underneath the `#ipad` element.

If you get rid of the `float:right` on `#selectedResult` and instead set it to:

```
position: absolute; 
right:0; 
top:0;
```

*And* set the `#ipad` element to:

```
position:relative;
```

Then the element will be fixed to the top and right sides of its parent.

You can see an updated version of your example here: http://jsbin.com/uxavov/edit#preview